# How to install docker in AWS EC2 and Port maping with domain

Tags: amazon-ec2

I faced a problem I create instance of ec2 AWS server and install docker so that docker is working find but I cant to able to map docker port with my domain Route 53

Answer (score 0):

Docker port needs to be exposed, something like this

```
docker run -p 80:8080 ubuntu bash
```

where 80 is exposed to the internet and 8080 is where your app is running

If you have your port exposed but not able to access it still, make sure you have required port opened in AWS security groups